patch doesn't work when called multiple times
I have a form and a button with which I want to send data from input fields to a table. The logic is as follows: there are AppId fields and two corresponding attribute fields. It should result in creating/updating two rows in the table.
The code goes like:
Set(var_DataSet_Name, TXTInput_Dataset_Name.Value);
Set(var_DataSet_Name_Lock, true);

If(
  IsBlank(LookUp('Table1', 'AppId' = TextInput1_1.Value)),
      Notify("no records found", NotificationType.Error),
  Patch('Table1', LookUp('Table1', 'AppId' = TextInput1_1.Value),
   {
    'attribute1': TextInput2_1.Value,
    'attribute2': TextInput3_1.Value
   }
  )
);

If(
  IsBlank(LookUp('Table1', 'AppId' = TextInput1_2.Value)),
      Notify("no records found", NotificationType.Error),
  Patch('Table1', LookUp('Table1', 'AppId' = TextInput1_2.Value),
   {
    'attribute1': TextInput2_2.Value,
    'attribute2': TextInput3_2.Value
   }
  )
);

Refresh('Table1');

The problem is that that only the first patch works, so only the the row defined with AppId' = TextInput1_1.Value gets updated and the attribute1 and attribute2 values are fetched from the form.
I tried different combinations to debug the issue. If I switch the order of patches in the code:
Set(var_DataSet_Name, TXTInput_Dataset_Name.Value);
Set(var_DataSet_Name_Lock, true);

If(
  IsBlank(LookUp('Table1', 'AppId' = TextInput1_2.Value)),
      Notify("no records found", NotificationType.Error),
  Patch('Table1', LookUp('Table1', 'AppId' = TextInput1_2.Value),
   {
    'attribute1': TextInput2_2.Value,
    'attribute2': TextInput3_2.Value
   }
  )
);

If(
  IsBlank(LookUp('Table1', 'AppId' = TextInput1_1.Value)),
      Notify("no records found", NotificationType.Error),
  Patch('Table1', LookUp('Table1', 'AppId' = TextInput1_1.Value),
   {
    'attribute1': TextInput2_1.Value,
    'attribute2': TextInput3_1.Value
   }
  )
);

Refresh('Table1');

then the other one works. And if I replace variables in both patches with fixed strings (   { 'attribute1': "aaa", 'attribute2': "bbb" }) it works for both of them. What could be the reason of such behaviour?

In both of your IsBlank functions, you are checking for 'AppId' = TextInput1.Value. But, while updating you are TextInput1_2 and TextInput1_2 as AppId, not sure that is intended!

yes, you are right, my mistake during rewriting. I corrected the code in my initial question
